# when trying to save a blog to database, @blog.save return false

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When trying to save a new blog, @blog.save always return false. This is how @blog look like: 
***Blog id: nil, title: "New Title", content: "New Content", users_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil***

Blogs Migration

```
class CreateBlogs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :blogs do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :content
      t.references :users, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Blog Controller Code

```
    def create
        @blog = Blog.new(blogParams)
        #render plain: @blog.inspect
        #return 
        if (@blog.save)
            render plain: "OK"
            #redirect_to 
        else
            render plain: @blog.inspect
        end
    end

    private def blogParams
        params.require(:newBlog).permit(:title, :content).merge(users_id: current_user.id)
    end
```

Comment: Try @blog.save! and please share the error message you received.

Comment: Try doing `@blog.save!` which will raise an error telling you what is wrong. To set `user_id`, try `@blog = current_user.blogs.new(blog_params)`. Note that `blogParams` is unconventional. Also, no need for parentheses around `@blog.save`. Also, also `users_id` is peculiar instead of `user_id`.

Comment: When trying @blog.save! It returns: Validation failed: User must exist

Comment: @jvillian it return: unknown attribute 'user_id' for Blog.
So maybe I make some mistakes when doing the migration?

Comment: How do your associations look? Using `users_id` rails will not be able to resolve automatically which class it points to. Better to change your migration to `t.references :user` (singular)  and then everything will behave as expected. One can make it work, but I think in this case it is just better to fix the typo (imho).

Comment: @jvillian I change Blogs Migration 
From ```t.references :users, foreign_key: true``` to ```t.references :user, foreign_key: true``` and then follow your step and it works. Thank a lot

Comment: @nathanvda already fix it. (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize you've already accepted an answer to this question, but I wanted to follow up on my comment to your original question.

First, a little table setting... As you have found, you need to do:

```
class CreateBlogs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :blogs do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :content
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

When including a foreign key in a model, it is conventional to use the singular of the referenced model rather than the plural.

Then, you should do something like:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

...in your blog model. Personally, I think I would do something more like:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
end
```

...so that it's more descriptive. But, that's a matter of personal preference. (And, you would need to change your migration accordingly.)

Then, you should do something like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blogs
end
```

If you like the `owner` approach, then something like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blogs, as: :owner
end
```

In your controller, you should fix your variable naming. As [described in the ruby style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars), snake case is prefered.

And, [according to the style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#spaces-indentation), indent using two spaces.

Also, as mentioned in my comment, no need for `(@blog.save)` - those parentheses don't do anything and only shorten your life to type.

So, `blogs_controller.rb` might look more like:

```
def create
  @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)
  if @blog.save
    render plain: "OK"
  else
    render plain: @blog.inspect
  end
end

private def blog_params
  params.require(:new_blog).permit(:title, :content).merge(users_id: current_user.id)
end
```

But, here's the real point!

If you have your associations set up correctly, as above, then you can (in your `BlogsController`), do something like:

```
def new
  @blog = current_user.blogs.build
end

def create
  @blog = current_user.blogs.build(new_blog_params)
  if @blog.save
    render plain: "OK"
  else
    render plain: @blog.inspect
  end
end

private def new_blog_params
  params.require(:new_blog).permit(:title, :content)
end
```

This will create your new `@blog` with the `user_id` set to `current_user.id`.

So what? When using rails associations, you get a bunch of methods (like [build](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection-build-attributes), but it depends on the type of association). And, often, these methods exist to help you with common tasks (like setting `user_id` on `@blog`). Your case is a relatively trivial example. But, it is worth studying [the guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) so that you can be sure to take advantage of all the work the nice people over in Railsland have done on your behalf.

Comment: Thank you very much, I learned a lot. I'm new to Rails and its syntax is really confused me with so much hidden rule like when to add S when don't . Again, thank a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In your controller blogs_controllers.rb, in new method  set :

```
@blog.user = current_user
```

and change your permitted_params like this :

params.require(:newBlog).permit(:title, :content, users_id)

I hope i've helped you.

edit :

As mentioned above, conventions require that user would be in the singular. Let's deal with it, it doesn't matter:

In your blog.rb model you must have this:

```
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "users_id"
```

Comment: Or the OP could just change the migration or add a new migration to remove the `users_id` and add `t.references :user` instead.